# Google Drive API: Cannot copy a shared file

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an application that copies files from one account to another using the Drive Api.

It first share the documents form source account to destination and then on destination makes a local copy of the shared file.

I has worked wel for some accounts until now. I have an account that the aplication can't copy the file. I get an authentication error such as the following:

```
{ errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'userAccess',
       message: 'The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file PKb_fEw17FE',
       locationType: 'header',
       location: 'Authorization' } ],
  code: 403,
  message: 'The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file PKb_fEw17FE' }
```

A few important things:

- The file descriptor in the error is not file_id the application tries
  to copy. In fact It changes every time you try to copy the file.
- The same error ocurrs when I try to do it manually using the Api
  explorer on the Drive developers
  site(https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy)
- I verified through the GUI and using the API explorer that the
  user that is making the copy has the proper permissions.
- When I do the copy using the Web Gui, it works without problems.

Could this be related to quotas?

An aditional piece of information:
  The requests body for the copy only includes the title for the new file. See the code below(nodejs)

```
var body = {'title': file.title };
var request = client.drive.files.copy({'fileId': file.id}, body);
        request.withAuthClient(auth2).execute(function (err, resp)
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the problem. It seems that when you copy a file without declaring the parent It sometimes copy it to the Root dir and some times tries to copy it in another place(I presume with the same parent as the original one).

I specified that all files should be copied to the root forlder adding the ID for the parent and the problem was solved.

```
var body = {'title': file.title,
            'parents': [ {'id': wr_new_parentroot} ]
            };
console.log('Request Body: %j', body);
var request = client.drive.files.copy({'fileId': file.id}, body);
request.withAuthClient(auth2).execute(function (err, resp) {
```